# Different headers in the same session

Tags: python, http

After I ran the following python script,

```
import requests

header_1 = {"Authorization":"Bearer abc123"}
header_2 = {"Authorization":"Bearer def456"}

url = "https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify"
session = requests.session()

a = session.post(url, headers=header_1, files=file, data=data)
print(a.json())

b = session.post(url, headers=header_2, files=file, data=data)
print(b.json())
```

I got the following error message.

```
{'status': 200, 'message': 'ok'}
{'status': 400, 'message': 'Invalid image.'}
```

I don't know why I can't POST twice using different headers. If I like to do so, how should I do?

**Another Try 1**

I have tried to clear the headers between two POSTs. But it doesn't work.

```
import requests

header_1 = {"Authorization":"Bearer abc123"}
header_2 = {"Authorization":"Bearer def456"}

url = "https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify"
session = requests.session()

a = session.post(url, headers=header_1, files=file, data=data)
print(a.json())

session.headers.clear() ########## new line

b = session.post(url, headers=header_2, files=file, data=data)
print(b.json())
```

**Another Try 2**

I also have tried to define different sessions. This got the same error message

```
import requests

header_1 = {"Authorization":"Bearer abc123"}
header_2 = {"Authorization":"Bearer def456"}

url = "https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify"

session_1 = requests.session()
session_2 = requests.session()

a = session_1.post(url, headers=header_1, files=file, data=data)
print(a.json())

b = session_2.post(url, headers=header_2, files=file, data=data)
print(b.json())
```

**Another Try 3**

If I changed the order of the POSTs. The first POST is ok and the second one got an error.

```
import requests

header_1 = {"Authorization":"Bearer abc123"}
header_2 = {"Authorization":"Bearer def456"}

url = "https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify"

session_1 = requests.session()
session_2 = requests.session()

b = session_2.post(url, headers=header_2, files=file, data=data)
print(b.json())

a = session_1.post(url, headers=header_1, files=file, data=data)
print(a.json())
```

Is there anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like the second authorization header is simply wrong. Does it work if you use that header by itself?

Comment: @Barmar Yes. The two headers work fine if I POST them individually. I have also tried to change the order of these two POSTs. The problem always occur on the "second" one.

Comment: So why do you insist on reusing the same session? The server may be caching your authorization token from the first request and reusing it for the second request, ignoring the authroization token in the header of the second request.

Comment: @blhsing Thanks for your comment. It is not necessary to use the same session. But I have tried to use two different sessions. It doesn't work. I need to use two different authorization tokens. I have also tried to clear the authorization token after the first request like using session.headers.clear(). But it doesn't work.

Comment: You said "The two headers work fine if I POST them individually" so I thought by "individually" you meant that you POST them in different sessions. But now that you say it doesn't work when you POST them in different sessions, I don't know what you mean anymore when you say it works fine when POSTed individually. Can you update your question with code that works when the two requests are POSTed individually?